# Relation does not exist, Spring Boot postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, entity, one-to-many

I am attempting to create an application with Spring Boot and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I believe it stems from my entity design but I am not sure how to go about fixing it. I have two entities that I want to be linked to. The aircraft entity must have a one-to-many relationship with the discrepancy entity. In my repository, I am using the JPA repository and the find-all method.

When using postman to send a get request to retrieve all aircraft objects, I receive this error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "aircraft.aircraft" does not exist
  Position: 152
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:181) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:133) ~[postgresql-42.4.0.jar:42.4.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:427) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy114.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.osprey.aircraft.AircraftServices.findAll(AircraftServices.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.osprey.aircraft.AircraftController.getAllAircraft(AircraftController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:an]
```

Here are the entities

Aircraft.java

```
@Entity(name = "Aircraft")
@Table(name = "aircraft", schema = "aircraft")
public class Aircraft {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="aircraft_sequence",
            sequenceName = "airacrft_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "aircraft_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name="id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name="buno",
            updatable = true,
            nullable = false,
            length = 6,
            unique = true
    )
    @Pattern(
            regexp ="^[0-9]*$",
            message = "A Buno is a 6 digit number that represents the aircraft"
    )
    private int buno;

    @Column(
            name="aircraft_type",
            updatable = true,
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String aircraftType;

    @Column(
            name = "aircraft_number",
            updatable = true,
            nullable = false,
            unique = true
    )
    private int aircraftNumber;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Discrepancies.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AircraftDiscrepancy_ForeignKey", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Discrepancies> discrepancies;

    public Aircraft(){

    }

    public Aircraft(int buno, String aircraftType, List<Discrepancies> discrepancies) {
        this.buno = buno;
        this.aircraftType = aircraftType;
        this.discrepancies = discrepancies;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBuno() {
        return buno;
    }

    public void setBuno(int buno) {
        this.buno = buno;
    }

    public String getAircraftType() {
        return aircraftType;
    }

    public void setAircraftType(String aircraftType) {
        this.aircraftType = aircraftType;
    }

    public List<Discrepancies> getDiscrepancies() {
        return discrepancies;
    }

    public void setDiscrepancies(List<Discrepancies> discrepancies) {
        this.discrepancies = discrepancies;
    }
}
```

Discrepancies.java

```
@Entity(name="Discrepancies")
@Table(name = "discrepancies", schema = "aircraft")
public class Discrepancies {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "discrepancy_sequence",
            sequenceName = "discrepancy_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "discrepancy_sequence"
    )
    private Long discrepancyID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Aircraft.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Aircraft aircraft;

    @Column(
            name = "discrepancy_title",
            updatable = false,
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String discrepancyTitle;

    @Column(
            name = "discrepancy_description",
            updatable =true,
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String discrepancyDescription;

    @Column(
            name="active",
            updatable = true,
            nullable = false
    )
    private boolean active = false;

    public Discrepancies(){

    }

    public Discrepancies(Long discrepancyID, String discrepancyTitle, String discrepancyDescription, boolean active) {
        this.discrepancyID = discrepancyID;
        this.discrepancyTitle = discrepancyTitle;
        this.discrepancyDescription = discrepancyDescription;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Aircraft getAircraft() {
        return aircraft;
    }

    public void setAircraft(Aircraft aircraft) {
        this.aircraft = aircraft;
    }

    public Long getDiscrepancyID() {
        return discrepancyID;
    }

    public void setDiscrepancyID(Long discrepancyID) {
        this.discrepancyID = discrepancyID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return discrepancyTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.discrepancyTitle = title;
    }

    public String getDiscrepancyDescription() {
        return discrepancyDescription;
    }

    public void setDiscrepancyDescription(String discrepancyDescription) {
        this.discrepancyDescription = discrepancyDescription;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
```

Any help provided on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This can be because the table is not present in your schema in the database.

In order to resolve this, you can set this property in the **application.properties** file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

This property if the table does not exist then it will create or if the table exists then alter the table.

Hope the problem is Solved.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: you don't have a table/view called 'aircraft' in the schema 'aircraft', Peraphs the table exists in the 'public' schema?